# pkg-config couldn't find header of zlib

Tags: linux, build, pkg-config

I have zlib and pkg-config installed and pkg-config could find zlib:

```
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep zlib
zlib                      zlib - zlib compression library
```

`pkg-config --libs` is working:

```
$ pkg-config --libs zlib
-lz
```

but `pkg-config --cflags` couldn't find header files of zlib:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags zlib
```

prints nothing

```
$ cat /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/zlib.pc
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=/usr/lib64
sharedlibdir=${libdir}
includedir=/usr/include

Name: zlib
Description: zlib compression library
Version: 1.2.7

Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -L${sharedlibdir} -lz
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Why pkg-config couldn't find zlib? (I'm using CentOS 7 if it matters)

Comment: I assume `pkg-config --cflags` is a typo for `pkg-config --cflags zlib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pkg-config` did find the cflags for zlib.

However, `/usr/include` is one of the default include paths searched by the compiler. Therefore `pkg-config` filters it from the output, so that the compiler won't search it twice.

For the same reason `--libs` produced only `-lz`, not including the library path `-L/usr/lib64` which is also a default.